# Difference between npm run start and node server.js

Tags: node.js, npm

What is the difference between running the application using

1)

```
node server.js
```

2. 

and making a script

```
"start" : "node server.js"
```

using

```
npm run start.
```

When i type

1)

```
node server.js | pino-pretty
```

in terminal there is an error

```
pino-pretty not found
```

2. 

When i make

```
"start": "node server.js | pino-pretty"
```

in package.json and type

```
npm run start
```

in terminal it works.

So apparently there is a fundamental difference between running the application in 1 and 2.

Comment: Per [npm run](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-run-script) docs: In addition to the shell's pre-existing PATH, npm run adds node_modules/.bin to the PATH provided to scripts. That's where you'll presumably find pino-pretty.

Comment: yeah @jarmod. **node server.js | node_modules/.bin/pino-pretty** also worked. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is PATH.

Per the [npm run](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-run-script) docs:

> In addition to the shell's pre-existing PATH, npm run adds node_modules/.bin to the PATH provided to scripts.

You'll find pino-pretty in `node_modules/.bin`.